# Casting a Collection of Objects to IEnumerable(Of Type)

Tags: .net, casting

I've got a ConfigurationSection in my app.config which includes a list of http Endpoints (~50). Each one has an optional priority (as well as a default).

I'd like to display this list in order.

```
Dim Config As MyConfigSection = DirectCast(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None).Sections("MySection"), MyConfigSection)
Dim Endpoints = MyConfigSection.InitialEndpoints
```

In this case `InitialEndpoints` is of type `Endpointcollection` which Inherits `ConfigurationElementCollection` and is just a noddy collection which is loosely typed.

The Endpoint collection happens to deal with `EndpointDefinition`s which in turn have a `Url`, `Priority`, etc...

I'd like to be able to do...

```
For Each E in Endpoints.OrderBy(function(x) x.Priority)
    ...
Next
```

Do I really need to create a new list/collection and transfer the objects across, casting them as I go?

Cheating and casting the collection as an `IEnumerable` resulted in an invalid cast (not entirely unexpected)

An alternate thought was to do something like...

```
Endpoints.Select(function(x) DirectCast(x, Endpointdefinition)).OrderBy(...)
```

But `EndpointCollection` isn't a list so doesn't benefit from the LINQ `Select()` extension. I could always implement `IList` but now it feels like I'm using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Can someone please point out the obvious way to do this? For reference, my EndpointCollection is below

```
<ConfigurationCollection(GetType(EndpointDefinition), AddItemName:="Endpoint")>
    Public Class EndpointCollection
        Inherits ConfigurationElementCollection

        Protected Overloads Overrides Function CreateNewElement() As ConfigurationElement
            Return New EndpointDefinition
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Function CreateNewElement(elementName As String) As ConfigurationElement
            Return New EndpointDefinition With {.Url = elementName}
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Function GetElementKey(element As ConfigurationElement) As Object
            Return DirectCast(element, EndpointDefinition).Url
        End Function

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CollectionType As ConfigurationElementCollectionType
            Get
                Return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Shadows Property Item(index As Integer) As EndpointDefinition
            Get
                Return CType(BaseGet(index), EndpointDefinition)
            End Get
            Set(value As EndpointDefinition)
                If Not (BaseGet(index) Is Nothing) Then
                    BaseRemoveAt(index)
                End If
                BaseAdd(index, value)
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

Comment: Most collections implement `IEnumerable`, which is what `LINQ` is defined on - you should be able to simply use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) directly on the collection.

Comment: I should but that throws an `source is not IEnumerable<>` ArgumentException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that your class implements `IEnumerable`, and not `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Since `EndpointCollection` inherits `ConfigurationElementCollection` and `ConfigurationElementCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, you can use the [`OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913) extension method (or [`Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx), if you want).

So you should be able to do the following:

```
Dim Endpoints = MyConfigSection.InitialEndpoints.OfType(Of Endpointdefinition).OrderBy(function(x) x.Priority)
```

or

```
Dim Endpoints = MyConfigSection.InitialEndpoints.Cast(Of Endpointdefinition).OrderBy(function(x) x.Priority)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you - I knew it had to be in there somewhere. Am I correct in understanding that this is actually filtering rather than converting and simply because all my elements are the same type, it works? (I'll accept as soon as the timeout is done)

Comment: Yes. `OfType` filters your colletion. In your case, you could use `Cast` instead.